# Unable to click the link to open the url in @toast-ui/react-editor in my app

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing an issue with the @toast-ui/react-editor package where clicking on a link in the editor always puts the editor in editable mode instead of opening the URL.

Version of @toast-ui/react-editor: "^3.2.3"